# Draw a Circular Red Marker with Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Using the Mapbox Android SDK, what is the best way to create a red circle marker? I know how to do this using MarkerOptions() but that is now deprecated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of the Mapbox Android SDK are you using? If you're on the latest (which I'd strongly recommend!), your best bet would be to use the [Annotation Plugin](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/#manager). There is a new [manager class structure](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/#manager) for different types of annotations. The [CircleManager](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-annotation/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/annotation/CircleManager.java) should allow you to do exactly what you're hoping to.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/CircleActivity.java) you can use as you build.